# Order of the finalize() operations in Java

Tags: java, oop, garbage-collection, finalize

I'm trying to understand an exercise about Java's garbage collector and the `finalize()` method.

```
public class Five {
    static int x = 1;
    class String5 {
        String s;
        String5() {
            this.s = ""+(++x);
        }
        public void finalize() {
            System.out.print(s);
        }
    }

    String5 a = new String5();
    void f() {
        String5 a = new String5();
    }
    public void finalize() {
        System.out.print("H");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Five a5 = new Five();
        a5.f();
        a5 = new Five();
        a5.f();
        System.gc();
        System.runFinalization();
    }
}
```

The exercise asks me to predict the output. The correct answer was `532H`. I predicted that the output should be `2H35`, and I don't understand why my ordering was incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the JLS, the Java language defines no order of the execution of `finalize` methods, so the actual order is an implementation detail.

[JLS 12.6. Finalization of Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6):

> The Java programming language imposes no ordering on finalize method calls. Finalizers may be called in any order, or even concurrently.

The order that you encountered seems to suggest a stack implementation - the 4th and last created instance of `String5` which is eligible for garbage collection is finalized first (printing `5`), followed by the 2nd and 1st (the 3rd is not eligible for garbage collection) which print `3` and `2`, and finally the first `Five` instance is finalized and prints `H`.

However, different JDK implementations may produce different order.

Comment: Oh... and so when my teacher asks for the correct order, there's a flaw in the question?

Comment: @EdoardoMeneghini Perhaps the correct answer is that there is no correct order, according to the JLS.

Comment: “different JDK implementations may produce different order” or produce no output at all or not print all characters or surprisingly print even more than expected. Because a) there is no guaranty that finalizers run at all, b) `gc()` and `runFinalization()` are only suggestions that might get ignored, but c) garbage collection/ finalization still might run *without* these hints, e.g. in the middle of the program and d) objects might get collected even when being referenced by a local variable if there is no subsequent use of the object, so the second `Five` instance might get collected as well.